# Why TikTok website blocks Selenium chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

TickTok site does not allow viewing user profiles when I use a browser launched with Selenium. I tried even just launching the browser and doing everything manually, this did not help.

Here is what I used to solve the problem, but that didn't help:

- Used different user agents
- Changed the window scale
- Changed the key ($cdc_*) in the chromedriver.exe to random

I note that without Selenium, in a normal browser, nothing is blocked for me. I use Chrome and Python.

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

opts = Options()

ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
opts.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
opts.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts, executable_path=r'driver/chromedriver2.exe')

link = 'https://www.tiktok.com/'
d.get(link)
inpute('Pause . . .')
d.quit()
```

Comment: Answer: Because they do not want anybody to automatically scrape their content...

Comment: how can they block selenium browser? what's the difference between a browser launched manually, and one launched by selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and added a few tweaks and executed your test and here was the observation:

> **Note**: This observation is specific to internet users from India.

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.tiktok.com/')
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html><head>
      <script>
      window._I18N_LANG_ = 'en';
      .
      </style>
      </head>
  <body style="margin-top: 0px;">
  <div class="root">
      <header style="top: 0px;">
      .
      </header>
      <section>
      <article>
         <p>Dear Users,</p>
          <p>
          On June 29, 2020 the Govt. of India decided to block 59 apps, including TikTok. We are in the process of
          complying with the Government of India's directive and also working with
          the government to better understand the issue and explore a course of action.
          </p>
          <p>
         Ensuring the privacy and security of all our users in India remains our utmost priority.
          </p>
          <p>
          TikTok India Team.
          </p>
          <p>
          Follow us on <a href="https://twitter.com/tiktok_in">Twitter</a> and <a href="https://instagram.com/indiatiktok?igshid=40wmgad5gauz">Instagram</a>.
          </p>
     </article>
      </section>
  </div>
  </body></html>
  ```

---

### Conclusion

This observation is perfectly in line with Govt. of India decission to block 59 apps, including TikTok which can be reproduced accessing the [TicTok Home Page](https://www.tiktok.com/) landing page manually.

Browser Snapshot:

[image: TicTok]